# fail to update documents with cursor.forEach

Tags: mongodb, meteor

This Meteor client code does not update the documents found as expected. The `console.log(res)` prints '0' when there are documents to be updated.
Why and how to fix it? Thanks

```js
MyCollection.find({
  class: 'check-filter'
}).forEach((obj) => {
  MyCollecction.update({
    obj
  }, {
    $set: {
      class: ''
    }
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your selector to use the object's `_id`:

```
MyCollection.find({ class: 'check-filter' }).forEach(obj => {
  MyCollection.update(obj._id, { $set: { class: '' }}, (err, res) => {
    if (!err) {
      console.log(res);
    }
  });
});
```

Also you have a typo where you're trying to do `MyCollecction.update` instead of `MyCollection.update`